# Why does adding an index to the end of str.split() method return the value of the index?

Tags: python

I am curious as to why adding [0] to the end of `version.split('.')` is able to return the value of the first element in the list?

My code:

```
version = '6.1.9'

version.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Have you looked at what only version.split(".") puts out?

Comment: `split` returns a list, by calling `[0]` you're accessing the first element of that list. You could easily gleam this by just looking at what `split` returned

Comment: In Python, `str.split()` will return a `list`

Comment: Yes. It returns a list: ['6', '1', '9']. I am curious as to how appending [0] to the end of the line is able to return 6 without having to reference the returned list at all.

Comment: because `version.split('.')` returns a list. You don't need to explicitly give it a name. It is returned and then you index it immediately using `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Because `version.split('.')` returns the list `['6','1','9']` and '6' is the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The `x.split(".")` splits your string on `.` character and returns a list which contains the elements. In your case the list will be `['6', '1', '9']`. The list is indexed from `0`. It means when you write `your_list[0]`, you access to zero element of list which is `6` in your case. I have written a little example for you, perhaps it will be more understandable for you.

**Code:**

```
version = "6.1.9"
split_version = version.split(".")
print("List after split: {}".format(split_version))
print("Zero element: {}".format(split_version[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
List after split: ['6', '1', '9']
Zero element: 6
```